# Run Net Share command in powershell script

Tags: function, powershell

I try to share a folder in powershell with net share command, i can't use group or user name for share permission because this script will be used on the systems with different os languages, for this reason i use group/user SID to set up share permissions.

Here is my script, my function work great outside of command. But my function dont work in "NET SHARE" cmd.

```
function Get-GroupName {
param ($SID)

$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid)
$objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value
}

# Share Folder + Set Share Permission SID Based
cmd /c net share MSI=C:\MSI /GRANT:(Get-GroupName -SID 'S-1-1-0'),READ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
cmd /c $( "net share MSI=C:\MSI /GRANT:""$(Get-GroupName -SID 'S-1-1-0')"",READ" )
```

But if you're on Windows 8 or newer, Windows Server 2012 or newer you can use the `Set-SmbShare` and `Grant-SmbShareAccess` cmdlets instead:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635727

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635705

Comment: thank you very much, it work great ! Do you know where i can get more information about how i must use my commands in "string".

Comment: You're welcome. I think this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx) will be helpful.

Comment: I would gladly help but I think that for readability and for the community it would be better to create a new question so I (and other people) can answer it.

Comment: And by the way I think I have the answer.

Comment: Ok i will create a new question.